# Python/pandas idiom for if/then/else

Tags: python, pandas

After performing calculations on an entire pandas dataframe, I need to go back and override variable calculations (often setting to zero) based on the value of another variable(s). Is there a more succinct/idiomatic way to perform this kind of operation?

```
df['var1000'][df['type']==7] = 0
df['var1001'][df['type']==7] = 0
df['var1002'][df['type']==7] = 0
...
df['var1099'][df['type']==7] = 0
```

Is there a pandas-y way to do something like this?

```
if (df['type']==7):
    df['var1000'] = 0
    df['var1001'] = 0
    df['var1002'] = 0
    ...
    df['var1099'] = 0
```

Comment: @cs95 how is this a duplicate of the question posted more than 4 years after?

Comment: @ayorgo duplicates do not only have to be fixed based on chronological ordering. IMO both of the answers in the other question do a good (better) job of answering the question than the answer below (that uses a deprecated function to add to things).

Comment: @cs95 I bet it'd spark quite a debate if mentioned on meta. Oh, wait... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651

Seems legit then, although making the banner misleading.

Btw, the reason I noticed is because of the reference from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#idioms

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
df.ix[df.type==7, ['var1001', 'var1002']] = 0
```

If you're doing it on all columns, you can just do `df.ix[df.type==7] = 0`.  Or of course if you have a list of the columns whose values you want to replace, you can pass that list in the second slot:

```
columnsToReplace = ['var1001', 'var1002', ...]
df.ix[df.type==8, columnsToReplace] = 0
```

Comment: And can use: `var10_cols = [col for col in df.columns if isinstance(col, basestring) and col.startswith('var10')]`

Comment: Nice! Came here from the cookbook!

Comment: ix is deprecated, use .loc instead.