# Pandas if/then/else logic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this,

```
 df=pd.DataFrame([2,4,6,2],columns=['x'])
 df['y']=[3,2,1,2]
 df['x_test']=['x_larger','x_larger','x_smaller','x_equal']
```

I am trying to do a if/then/else, similar to  this [idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128302/python-pandas-idiom-for-if-then-else) and [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html). I am able to get one if statement correct but I am not sure how to test for equal.

```
df['valid']=False
df['invalid']=True
df.ix[(df.x_test=="x_larger") & (df.x>df.y),['valid','invalid']]=[True,False]
```

This works partially. But I would also like to test for x_equal in this line. Is that possible?

The desired output should be

```
    x  y     x_test  valid invalid
0  2  3   x_larger  False    True
1  4  2   x_larger   True   False
2  6  1  x_smaller  False    True
3  2  2    x_equal   True   False
```

Comment: Can you show your efforts, thanks

Comment: I think you make this harder by trying to set 'valid' and 'invalid' at the same time.  Just set 'valid' and then do `df['invalid'] = ~df['valid']`.  I'm not even sure what the point is of such a redundant column though.

Comment: 3 votes to close and 2 downvotes? This doesn't seem like a bad question to me (although it's really basic). Maybe you have a bad reputation because you almost never accept answers?  Or did something else to piss off at least 3 people.  Beats me.

Comment: haters going to hate. so, what I did was do this in multiple steps and it seems to work but not elegant.

Comment: I see you accepted some old answer, that could be good for karma.  If you search for answers with `np.where` and `np.select` you might find some more elegant solutions though I don't see much advantage for what you are trying to do here.